# Extra space in starting of html table

Tags: html

Can anyone help me out why there is an extra space in my HTML table. here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dg4z8rou/1/

```
Dear mohammad,<br/><br/>Thank you for your recent Research and Education Week 2017 abstract submission. Your abstract was copyedited for capitalization and spelling and the change(s) made can be viewed in the “Edited Abstract” column below. Please contact research@sh.org if you have any issues with your edited abstract. <br/><br />
<table style="border:1px solid black;width:100%;padding:0 8px;border-collapse: collapse ">
<tr>
<th style="border: 1px solid black ;">Original Abstract</th>
<th style="border: 1px solid black ;">Updated Abstract</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border: 1opes are equally important to adolescents and parents.</td></tr></table>}
```

you can see that Title under Updated Abstract is starting after 2 line spaces. I dont know from where it is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the CSS property '[vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)' on the TD. By default this value is set to 'baseline', that's why you have an extra space on top, but also at the bottom.

```
td {
  vertical-align: top
}
```

Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dg4z8rou/3/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your recent Research and Education Week 2017 abstract submission. Your abstract was copyedited for capitalization and spelling and the change(s) made can be viewed in the “Edited Abstract” column below. Please contact research@sh.org if you have any issues with your edited abstract.
    
    
    Original Abstract
    Updated Abstract
    
    
    }

Comment: its just  the <br/> remove it

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use valign attribute in TD itself.

```
<td style="border: 1px solid black ;" valign="top">
```